# .exe file gives error when I try to run it in C# window form

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I am making speech to text app in C# window form it was working fine and running in vs but

when I made a exe file and then try to run it's show error

It seemed to work fine, and created build  However, when I try to run the executable, I get the following error:

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpeechConfig.speech_config_from_subscription(IntPtr& config, String subscriptionKey, String region)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(String subscriptionKey, String region)
   at WindowsFormsApp5.Form1.<RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at WindowsFormsApp5.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpeechConfig.speech_config_from_subscription(IntPtr& config, String subscriptionKey, String region)
   at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(String subscriptionKey, String region)
   at WindowsFormsApp5.Form1.<RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync>d__0.MoveNext()<---



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsApp5
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/sars/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ZJ219HRQ.5KL/ET7TTANM.RTB/wind..tion_0f35f8da978c8171_0001.0000_3df998e5cb956487/WindowsFormsApp5.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4488.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4515.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp
    Assembly Version: 1.23.0.28
    Win32 Version: 1.23.0.28
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/sars/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/ZJ219HRQ.5KL/ET7TTANM.RTB/wind..tion_0f35f8da978c8171_0001.0000_3df998e5cb956487/Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your bin folder?

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZJLdVSJ

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZJLdVSJ @Humayun Shabbir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is common if you have tried to distribute just the .exe file from the compiled binaries. If this is the case, you should ensure that *all* the dlls and pretty much everything in the bin folder from you compiler output is distributed, this is referred to as an XCOPY deployment.

If you are using click-once deployment, then in the Application Files section of the publish options, make sure that all of the referenced files are included:
[image]

[image]

Comment: ok thank you @Chris Schaller I will check

Answer (score 1):

it may be a versioning problem. check if you have the necessary versions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio installed.

Also, loading packages.config sometimes behaves incorrectly in newer versions of Visual Studio. Try following the steps from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on packages.config and select "Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...."
2. In the opening dialog, there should be Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Core in Top-level dependencies by default and no package compatibility issues.
3. Select OK to begin the migration.
4. After the migration is completed, rebuild the solution which should then run without problems.

Hope that helps

Comment: still showing error

Comment: still showing error @ProxyProchy

Comment: try moving the whole project to another folder (e.g. documents) and make sure you have all the necessary things in the exe file folder.

If you download the official samples from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk , can you run the exe files building them?